# Response.redirect response is not available in context. if used with a timer.

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

I am trying to show a loading animation in a page for 6 seconds then redirect page.

If I use `Response.Redirect(@"~\WorklistPage.aspx", true);` in `Page_Load` it redirects page to worklistpage as expected.

But when I try to delay the redirect function, it throws an exception.

Below what I tried and not working. I get `response is not available in context` error

```
protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
            aTimer.Interval = 6000;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;

            //timer = new System.Threading.Timer(obj => { Response.Redirect(@"~\WorklistPage.aspx", true); }, null, 3000, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
            //Response.Redirect(@"~\WorklistPage.aspx", true);


        }

        private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            aTimer.Enabled = false;
            //HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(@"~\WorklistPage.aspx");
            //Response.Redirect(@"~\WorklistPage.aspx",true);
            //Response.Redirect(@"~\WorklistPage.aspx",false);
            //Server.Transfer(@"~\WorklistPage.aspx", true);

        }
```

Why I am getting an error, how can I fix it?

Comment: You need to read a primer on how the http protocol and the Asp.Net page life cycle work. Once you have a firm grounding there, it will be obvious what your problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is if you want to automatically redirect the browser six seconds after the page loads you need to do it in JavaScript not on the server. How do you expect a thread fired off on the server in the code behind to tell the browser to redirect to another page 6 seconds after it has returned the http response? You can do this kind of thing with signalr but it is massive overkill for a simple redirect.

Answer (score 3):

its impossible to call a web page from ServerSide with delay u must use java script.... u must use somthing like this For Example:

```
protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "success", "alert('Submitted Successfully.'); setInterval(function(){location.href='http://www.google.com';},3000);", true);
}
```